# Jetty Connection-Reset Timeouts Alerting

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9, connection-reset

Using embedded Jetty 9.4.x and QueuedThreadPool

In a scenario when there is way too few threads to handle Jetty tasks the QTP queue grows

New Connections have a timeout of 30secs and if in these 30secs the task is not picked from the Queue the connection is dropped. If this happens there is only a DEBUG msg thrown by JettyContainer.

Is there any way to setup a warning LOG messages for alerting purposes? I was trying to explore different EventListeners eg. HttpChannel.Listener, unfortunately it does not have a method exposed for when the connection is dropped due to timeout. Are there any other options or any other listener that can give access to that event?

The reason why I want to set this up is that I have several servers behind load balancer and if one of these gets into some issues, there is no easy way to find out which of the servers drops the connections

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I couldn't find a way either...